# Bad Receiver type 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

Tags: iphone, nsinteger

```
int thumbCount = [_totalThumbs thumbsViewNumberOfThumbs:self];
```

1. _totalThumbs is a NSInteger type property.
2. thumbsViewNumberOfThumbs is a method of type NSInteger.

I need to get the count in 'int' itself so that i can use it for further calculations.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Without seeing how and where `thumbsViewNumberOfThumbs:` is declared, I can only guess you should do `[self thumbsViewNumberOfThumbs:_totalThumbs]` instead of opposite. You can't call an instance method on its property, only on the, well, class instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int thumbCount = [self thumbsViewNumberOfThumbs:_totalThumbs];
```

Answer (score 4):

This question doesn't quite make sense.

First of all, `NSInteger` is not a class. It's a typedef for `long long`. That means, **you can't use it as an Objective-C message receiver.**

What you possibly want is that call this `thumbsViewNumberOfThumbs:` method on the object whose class implements it and assign that to an `NSInteger`. Or assign it to an `int` directly - for such a simple case, `int` and `NSInteger` are compatible types (assuming you don't want to work with such big numbers who don't fit into an `int`...)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is right: `NSInteger` is not a type that could possibly have methods, because it is not an *`id`*-derived type.

If you have a method that *takes* `NSInteger` as parameter, you pass it after the colon `:`, not as the receiver of the method.